# Thymeleaf Issue - variable gets printed instead of value

Tags: thymeleaf

The following code just print the text ${result.empno} instead of the employee number sent from the back-end

```
 <p class="sent-text">Sent to <span th:text="${result.empno}"></span></p>
```

What would be the cause of the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. For example: If the Thymeleaf template is processed normally, then `${result.empno}` is evaluated & replaced correctly. If the template is opened as a web page without being processed by Thymeleaf, then only the text `sent to` is displayed. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Thanks and i understood the problem now.